# predicate logic proof of 2 numbers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

For any two different numbers there is an number in between.

I'm trying to write this in predicate logic and have no idea how to do it, since I need 2 variables X and Y?  For all x there exists a y such that y - x is positive?

I'm a mong ignore.

Comment: Hint: *for any $x$ and $y$, there is a $z$ such that ...*

Answer (score 1):

As a hint, for any two numbers there is a third number in between.